# Meaning of a Common String In Executables?

Tags: macos, executable, elf, binary-data, mach

There appear to be some similar-looking long alphanumeric strings that commonly occur in Mach-O 64 bit executables and ELF 64-bit LSB executables among other symbols that are not alphanumeric:

```
cat /bin/bash | grep -c "AWAVAUATSH"
```

has 181 results, and

```
cat /usr/bin/gzip | grep -c "AWAVAUATSH"
```

has 9 results.

[image]

What are these strings?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Interesting question. Since I didn't know the answer, here are the steps I took to figure it out:

Where in the file does the string occur?

```
strings -otx /bin/gzip | grep AWAVAUATUSH
   35e0 AWAVAUATUSH
   69a0 AWAVAUATUSH
   7920 AWAVAUATUSH
   8900 AWAVAUATUSH
   92a0 AWAVAUATUSH
```

Which section is that in?

```
readelf -WS /bin/gzip

There are 28 section headers, starting at offset 0x16860:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        0000000000400238 000238 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            0000000000400254 000254 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            0000000000400274 000274 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0000000000400298 000298 000038 00   A  5   0  8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          00000000004002d0 0002d0 000870 18   A  6   1  8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000400b40 000b40 000360 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          0000000000400ea0 000ea0 0000b4 02   A  5   0  2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         0000000000400f58 000f58 000080 00   A  6   1  8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA            0000000000400fd8 000fd8 000090 18   A  5   0  8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA            0000000000401068 001068 0007e0 18   A  5  12  8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        0000000000401848 001848 00001a 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        0000000000401870 001870 000550 10  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000401dc0 001dc0 00f1ba 00  AX  0   0 16
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS        0000000000410f7c 010f7c 000009 00  AX  0   0  4
... etc.
```

From above output, we see that all instances of `AWAVAUATUSH` are in `.text` section (which covers `[0x1dc0, 0x10f7a)` offsets of the file.

Since this is `.text`, we expect to find executable instructions there. The address we are interested in is `0x401dc0` (`.text` address) + `0x35e0` (offset of `AWAVAUATUSH` in the file) - `0x1dc0` (offset of `.text` in the file) == `0x4035e0`.

First, let's check that the above arithmetic is correct:

```
gdb -q /bin/gzip

(gdb) x/s 0x4035e0
0x4035e0:       "AWAVAUATUSH\203\354HdH\213\004%("
```

Yes, it is. Next, what are the instructions there?

```
(gdb) x/20i 0x4035e0
   0x4035e0:    push   %r15
   0x4035e2:    push   %r14
   0x4035e4:    push   %r13
   0x4035e6:    push   %r12
   0x4035e8:    push   %rbp
   0x4035e9:    push   %rbx
   0x4035ea:    sub    $0x48,%rsp
   0x4035ee:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x4035f7:    mov    %rax,0x38(%rsp)
   0x4035fc:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x4035fe:    mov    0x213363(%rip),%rax        # 0x616968
   0x403605:    mov    %rdi,(%rsp)
   0x403609:    mov    %rax,0x212cf0(%rip)        # 0x616300
   0x403610:    cmpb   $0x7a,(%rax)
   0x403613:    je     0x403730
   0x403619:    mov    $0x616300,%ebx
   0x40361e:    mov    (%rsp),%rdi
   0x403622:    callq  0x4019f0 <strlen@plt>
   0x403627:    cmp    $0x20,%eax
   0x40362a:    mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
```

These indeed look like normal executable instructions. What is the opcode of `push %r15`? [This table](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_1.htm) shows that `0x41`, `0x57` is indeed `push %r15`, and these opcodes just *happen* to spell `AW` in `ASCII`. Similarly, `push %r14` is encoded as `0x41`, `0x56`, which just happens spell `AV`. Etc.

P.S. My version of gzip is fully stripped, which is why GDB shows no symbols in the above disassembly. If I use a non-stripped version instead, I see:

```
strings -o -tx gzip | grep AWAVAUATUSH | head -1
   6be0 AWAVAUATUSH

readelf -WS gzip | grep text
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000401b00 001b00 00d102 00  AX  0   0 16
```

So the string is still in `.text`.

```
gdb -q ./gzip
(gdb) p/a 0x0000000000401b00 + 0x6be0 - 0x001b00
$1 = 0x406be0 <inflate_dynamic>

(gdb) disas/r 0x406be0
Dump of assembler code for function inflate_dynamic:
   0x0000000000406be0 <+0>:     41 57   push   %r15
   0x0000000000406be2 <+2>:     41 56   push   %r14
   0x0000000000406be4 <+4>:     41 55   push   %r13
   0x0000000000406be6 <+6>:     41 54   push   %r12
   0x0000000000406be8 <+8>:     55      push   %rbp
   0x0000000000406be9 <+9>:     53      push   %rbx
   0x0000000000406bea <+10>:    48 81 ec 38 05 00 00    sub    $0x538,%rsp
...
```

Now you can clearly see the `ASCII` `0x4157415641554154...` sequence of opcodes.

P.P.S. The original question asks about `AWAVAUATSH`, which does appear in my Mach-O `bash` and `gzip`, but not in Linux ones. Conversely, `AWAVAUATUSH` does not appear in my Mach-O binaries.

The answer is however the same. The `AWAVAUATSH` sequence is the same as `AWAVAUATUSH`, but with `push %rbp` omitted.

P.P.P.S Here are some other "fun" strings of the same nature:

```
strings /bin/bash | grep '^A.A.A.' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
     44 AWAVAUATUSH
     27 AVAUATUSH
     16 AWAVAUA
     15 AVAUATUH
     14 AWAVAUI
     14 AWAVAUATUH
     12 AWAVAUATI
      8 AWAVAUE1
      8 AVAUATI
      6 AWAVAUATU
```

Comment: I wish your answer would reach a wide audience, I learned a lot about examining executables from this answer.

Comment: Google search shows that others knew this answer: https://plus.google.com/+EmilMikulic/posts/L13sdZNRhL9 and https://www.jwz.org/blog/2014/10/we-live-in-a-magical-future-where-strings-is-exploitable/#comment-158250 so that's another way to solve this: just Google for it ;-)

Comment: `echo -n AWAVAUATUSH | rasm2 -B -a x86 -b 64 -Df -` quite conveniently disassembles the sequence.