# why does an object file(.o files in linux) look gibberish when opened with vim text editor?

Tags: linux, vim, operating-system, system, elf

what are the symbols that we see when we open object files with text editor, do they(symbols like @,..) have any meaning? Since object file is a binary file, we expect to see 1's and 0's but why do we see those symbols?

Comment: You misunderstand the term `binary file`. It is not the same as `binary notation`

Answer (score 4):

Because a binary file contains binary data, not the ASCII data that your text editor is expecting to see. It is up to the editor how it will display "non printable" characters.

On Linux you can use `od` to dump a file in other formats (octal, hex, binary) if you really want to see the 0s and 1s.

Comment: "ASCII data that your text editor is expecting to see" -- there is no such thing as "ASCII data". It's bits all the way down.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Are you seriously arguing that a text editor doesn't apply some interpretation to the data? If it was just "bits", then the OPs question is very fair- you would expect it to just show 0s and 1s...

Answer (score 3):

The symbols you’re seeing are [C0 Codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29) in [caret notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) and they represent non-printing ASCII characters.

[`.o` files](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) don’t contain human-readable text, so they look like nonsense when Vim tries to read them as ASCII.

If you’d like to see these characters as their component bytes (like `<00>` instead of `^@`), try `:set display+=uhex` (see also `:help display`).

Answer (score 0):

> Since object file is a binary file, we expect to see 1's and 0's

Your expectation is *incorrect*. If you want to see 0s and 1s, you need to use a tool that displays 0s and 1s.

I can find no standard utility that would do this, and nobody ever really wants to see 0s and 1s, because such a display would be very verbose. Programmers prefer hexadecimal display, which is much more compact. For example, the hex value `0xfd` can be expressed as the following sequence of 0s and 1s: `1111 1101`.

Note 1: It's exactly the same sequence of 0s and 1s, expressed in different way.

Note 2: You can see that expressing numbers as bits quickly gets out of hand: `0xfffffffd` is `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101`

> but why do we see those symbols?

The `vim` editor *interprets* the sequence of 0s and 1s as `ASCII` characters. For example, `ASCII` code for 'A' is `0x41`, or the following sequence of 0s and 1s: `0100 0001`. Full `ASCII` table [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html).

To understand this better, create a file `foo.txt` in `vim` that has the following lines:

```
AAAAaaaa
BBBBbbbb
```

Then run this file through:

```
od -c foo.txt
od -b foo.txt
od -tx1 foo.txt
cat foo.txt
```

Note that the 0s and 1s contained in the file *do not* change, but each of the above commands *interprets* these 0s and 1s differently.

Back to your binary file.

*All* files contain a sequence of bytes. These bytes can be interpreted differently by different tools.

When people say "binary file" vs. "text file", what they usually mean is that the latter contains *only* bytes that have printable `ASCII` characters associated with them, and the former contains some bytes that have *non*-printable `ASCII` characters (it is very common for a binary file to also contain bytes that correspond to printable `ASCII`. There is a [strings](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) utility which can extract such printable sequences of bytes from "binary files" and interpret them as "text". Note that sometimes that interpretation makes a "mistake", and interprets binary data as a printable string, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322552/meaning-of-a-common-string-in-executables).